# Error con certificado ssl en servidor

Tags: ssl, https, letsencrypt

Actualmente cuento con un VPS al cual le instale un certificado SSL de Let's Encrypt. Al entrar al dominio [jesushenriquez.com](https://jesushenriquez.com) el navegador detecta que es una conexión segura, el problema esta cuando ingreso a un post por ejemplo: [Publicación](https://jesushenriquez.com/blog/instalacion-de-laravel-lumen). Al entrar el navegador muestra lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He tratado de revisar toda la estructura y no logro dar con lo que esta generando que no detecte bien la conexión segura.

**Es una aplicación creada con laravel alojada en un vps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según el navegador Chrome, el problema es por "contenido mixto", o sea, tu página es "https" pero tiene contenido "http" (esto normalmente rompe las conexiones seguras). Prueba editando la hoja de estilo "new_styles.css" (URL: https://jesushenriquez.com/mcard/css/new_styles.css), línea 139: ahí aparece "http://beshley.com/android-search.png", agrégale la "s" al "http", guarda este cambio y luego abre [la publicación](https://jesushenriquez.com/blog/instalacion-de-laravel-lumen) en una ventana de incógnito para chequear.

Me comentas si funcionó.

Saludos.

Comment: Funciono! si sabia de ese tipo error, pero no lograba dar con la url http (no segura) y nunca se me ocurrio buscar en los css. Gracias.